# Scroll indicator of a single html element

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, onscroll

I'm trying to create a scroll indicator regarding a single HTML element. In my page I have a paragraph with overflow set to "scroll".
Problem is, I tried many methods and each of them only seem to work on the "main" scroll event of the whole page.

Following is my adaptation of the code found at:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_indicator.asp

I assigned the class name "content" to my < p >.

```
    <script> 

window.body.getElementsByClassName("content").onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.getElementsByClassName("content").scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

Gave this a shot to no avail, unfortunately. 
That may be due to the fact I'm still learning.
Attached is also a preview of the current page.

As you can see, the grey scroll indicator is on top of it but it doesn't work when I scroll through the paragraph (< p >).
It may be quite simple but I can't figure this out.

```
<div class="header">
<div class="progress-container">
<div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div></div></div>


<a class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? [33] At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.<br>
```

Thank you in advance!

[image: Preview]

Comment: Add your html too, and look into how to create a code snippet here

Comment: Sure. Done it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So...

been manipulating my code a little bit.
This is what I found to work:

1. I assigned an id to my element, in this case "par".
2. I assigned " onscroll="myFunction()" " to my  element.
3. (Optional) I assigned a class to style my element.
4. And then I inserted a javascript function inside my html file as a script (you can have a separate .js file, if you prefer so) with the following code. **Keep in mind you must refer to your element with the same ID**

   < a class="content" onscroll="myFunction()" id="par">Your paragraph content < /a >

   ```
   <script>

   function myFunction() {
     var winScroll = document.getElementById("par").scrollTop || document.getElementById("par").scrollTop;
     var height = document.getElementById("par").scrollHeight - document.getElementById("par").clientHeight;
     var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
     document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
   }

   </script>
   ```

Hope this will clear some doubts about my question. This may look uber-simple to some of you but it wasn't on my part. Have a nice day!